# Angular 10: Still recommending TSLint Or ESLint program?

Tags: angular, typescript, eslint, tslint, angular10

Why is Angular 10 making its Default Lint Program TSLint, when its deprecated? Does Angular recommend TSLint or ESLint?

https://angular.io/cli/lint

https://palantir.github.io/tslint/

Comment: I assume because migration is going to be a major undertaking and ts-lint still works with the latest very TypeScript thus far. Consider that the Angular ecosystem widely uses custom ts-lint rules.

Comment: hi @AluanHaddad feel free to place as answer, yeah, all these websites are saying recommend to ESLint, we tried migrating today, but got many unknown rule was not found errors

Comment: Honestly, I don't want to answer because I don't have experience migrating a large project and there isn't much for me to say aside from the obvious. One thing that seems to be confusing large numbers of users who are migrating is their, IMO baseless, assumption that any and all existing ESLint rules can and should be applicable to TypeScript.

Comment: People may consider this a low quality question, but closing this as _Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more_, would be incorrect in my view.

Comment: yeah, not sure why they are voting down? trying to learn

Comment: It's not a great question. You don't really ask something that can be answered except by the Angular team member(s) responsible for these decisions and you don't demonstrate much research effort. You can do better but the close reason is invalid.

Comment: sometimes when I ask questions, Microsoft or AWS will directly answer

Comment: But I think the downvotes are justified. Googling _github angular eslint_ returned this as the 3rd result: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/13732.

Comment: well, I did put in research, we actually migrated (took 3 hours today), but before final code review, want to make sure

Comment: Indeed? I respect that. However, excepting an Angular team member answering here, which seems unlikely given the lack of official guidance in documentation, all we can do is muse over the state of things, as I am at this moment.

Comment: https://github.com/angular-eslint/angular-eslint - I think the answer is that Angular gives you a path forward. The underlying package is deprecated and was at the time this question was asked. And does Angular really recommend deprecated projects???